# Python Lambda Issue TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, lambda, anonymous-function

I am trying to define a lambda expression in python 3 for the following function in my class:

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.myReqData= lambda x : self.reqData(x['reqId'],x['description'],'',False,False,[])
        print(self.myReqData) #  this gives me <function MyClass.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f9af04a50e0>
```

`reqData()` is inherited from the parent class `BaseClass` and its return type is `None`. It just connects to the server and places a request for data.

As soon as I use the function in my class, I get the TypeError:

```
    self.myReqData(mydata)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

There is definitely something python does not like about my lambda expression that I can't see. To me, `self.myReqData(mydata)` is equivalent to `self.reqData(mydata['reqId'], mydata['description'], '', False, False, [])` which should work.

Could someone kindly help?

Comment: Where is the `self.myReqData` defined? My hunch is that the function is called before it is defined, hence resulting in a `NoneType` error. @AFP

Comment: That's a good point, but I define `self.myReqData` after I initialize the base class.

Comment: So it's in `__init__` function of the inherited class? The code is correct, program flow might be wrong.

Comment: Correct. I first do `BaseClass.__init__(self)`, then the next statement is `self.myReqData= lambda x : self.reqData(x['reqId'],x['description'],'',False,False,[])`

Comment: Do a print after the lambda definition and check `print(self.myReqData)` (Basic debugging)

Comment: `print(self.myReqData)` gives me `<function MyClass.__init__.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f9af04a50e0>`

Comment: Please print `myReqData` und `reqData` just before calling it. It might be that not `myReqData` but `reqData` is `None` (is it a method or another lambda?)